# idiomatic way to replace (null x) function from common lisp in clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp, common-lisp, idioms

In Common Lisp you use the (null x) function to check for empty lists and nil values.

Most logically this maps to

```
(or (nil?  x) (= '() x))
```

In clojure. Can someone suggest a more idiomatic way to do it in Clojure?

Comment: In Lisp, `NIL` and `()` (the empty list) are one and the same thing.  Your code snippet is a pleonasm.

Comment: Not in Clojure: `(= '() nil) => false`. 

In other Lisps, this is true.

Comment: Svante: Your statement might not be true in Clojure but I have a new favorite word.

Comment: There is no null? in CL, only null (and endp).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the **same result for an empty list in Clojure as you do in Common Lisp**, use the `empty?` function. This function is in the core library: **no imports are necessary.**

It is also a predicate, and suffixed with a **`?`**, making it a little clearer what exactly you're doing in the code.

```
=> (empty? '())
true
=> (empty? '(1 2))
false
=> (empty? nil)
true
```

As j-g faustus already noted, `seq` can be used for a similar effect.

Comment: Your answer is better, since it also works with vectors, maps, strings etc. without converting them to seqs. I suppose the seq approach is suitable if you have an argument of unknown type and want to operate on a seq.

Comment: j-g-faustus: I wish. The defn is `(defn empty? [coll] (not (seq coll)))`.

Comment: Hah, wow, can't believe we missed that. Two years later, but definitely good to know and have here.

Comment: Citation link: [Clojure `empty?` function documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/empty_q). See source code by expanding the Source box.

Answer (score 10):

> seq also serves as test for end,
>   already idiomatic
>
> ```
> (when (seq coll)
>   ...)
> ```

From [clojure.org lazy](http://clojure.org/lazy)

It works because `(seq nil)` and `(seq ())` both return nil.

And since `nil` means `false`, you don't need an explicit nil test.